# PHP fails to load php_lzw.dll under Windows 11 in XAMPP / PHP 8.2.4 saying that file is missing while it loads all other extensions without problems

Tags: php, dll, xampp, windows-11

What is the proper way of adding a dynamic library do XAMPP / PHP 8.2.4? What other steps must I undertake in order to achieve it (be able to use that extension in PHP) beside:

- copying the corresponding file to *C:\XAMPP\php\ext* folder
- adding `extension=lzf` (in my case) to *php.ini*

Currently this is not working (or, please, explain what am I missing):

[image]

To be honest, I have absolutely no idea, what is going on here!

I have two files:

- *php_lzf.dll* and
- *php_sqlite3.dll*  (and many more of course)

residing in *C:\XAMPP\php\ext* folder. And I have two entries:

- `extension=lzf` and
- `extension=pdo_sqlite` (plus many more)

added to my *php.ini* file

And the first one is not being loaded (and PHP claims that the file is missing -- the weirdest part) while the second one (plus many more) is being loaded without any problems at every PHP startup.

This is so weird case that I don't even know where to start tracing it.

Comment: try `extension=lzf` instead of  `extension=php_lzf.dll`

Comment: Just quickly create a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` file and load it in your browser. That way you can quickly check which `php.ini` file is being loaded and which libraries it has etc. I find this the easiest way to solve issues like this.

Comment: @InDevX Really sorry for misleading information. I have corrected the question. The actual  entry in _php.ini_ was already `extension=lzf`. PHP seems to be adding the remaining part. When I changed it to `extension=lzf.dll`, I have got and error about missing `C:\XAMPP\php\ext\php_lzf.dll.dll` extension. And when I changed this to `extension=php_lzf` then the error was about missing `C:\XAMPP\php\ext\php_php_lzf.dll` extension.

Comment: @icecub Thanks for trying to help, but that is not a case. I have put `extension=pdo_sqlite` into a comment in my _php.ini_ for a moment and refreshing page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` showed that _pdo_sqlite_ extension is gone. Removed the comment, restarted the server again and the extension is again loaded. So I am editing the correct _php.ini_ (XAMPP has many of them for some reason) and the file is being correctly loaded upon PHP startup.

Answer (score 0):

[According to XAMPP Support Forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=82980&sid=08004350a7c08963c7b04aa92e01b76e&p=279338#p279338), it is impossible to use any 3rd party extension, even the official ones (like LZF in my case), other than the extension set, XAMPP already ships with. This is supposedly due to complex nature of XAMPP infrastructure and the PHP build that ships underneath (emphasis mine):

> **You can only activate extensions, which are coming with the XAMPP installation.**
>
> The DLLs. have to fit precisely(!) the infrastructure of the XAMPP Build (many parameters have to be fulfilled), which is quite impossible to achieve.
>
> XAMPP for Windows is using the default binaries from php.net (VS16 (Visual Studio 2019) x64 TS). So if you want to be able to load your extension, it needs to be built against this environment.
>
> Most problem of not loading user or other third party dlls are that they are not build against this environment.
>
> **If you need to have LZF extension, you cannot use XAMPP**.

Source: [XAMPP Support Forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=82980&sid=08004350a7c08963c7b04aa92e01b76e&p=279338#p279338).